# How to prevent ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: android

I know there are a lot of questions around this, but none are like mine.so here's my question:

how can i prevent ConcurrentModificationException when i want to remove an item from a list and i have to loop the list at the same in onDraw. here is my code:

```
   override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        circles.forEach {
            canvas?.drawCircle(it.circleWidth , it.circleHeight, it.circleRadius, it.painter)
        }
    }
```

```
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            val x :Float = event.x
            val y :Float = event.y

            circles.forEach {
                val circleX = it.circleWidth
                val circleY = it.circleHeight

                if ((abs(circleX - x) < circleRadius) && (abs(circleY - y) < circleRadius)) {
                    circleUtility.removeCircle(it)
                }
                return@forEach
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }
```

function removeCircle in circleUtility:

```
  fun removeCircle(circle :Circle) {
circles.remove(circle)
}
```

```
class Circle( val circleWidth: Float, var circleHeight :Float , val circleRadius :Float , val painter: Paint)
```

This my first time training on building a working game, i am not really sure if it's optimal to use `forEach` loop in `onDraw` . thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen the ConcurrentModificationException? What's the call stack? I think all this is executed on the same thread, right? I haven't tried it, but I think it should no have problems with concurrency. By the way, is return@forEach placed correctly?

Comment: It is at circles.remove(circle) its all running on main ui thread

Comment: OK, not really an extensive answer, but I'd suggest using synchronized on the circles instance variable. This could have some performance impact though, so in case that's a problem, you may want to explore more options. This article gives some ideas https://proandroiddev.com/synchronization-and-thread-safety-techniques-in-java-and-kotlin-f63506370e6d